# Conditionals used with past tense in one sentence

Tags: tense, past-tense, conditional-constructions

> I have been aiming at creating a facture which would give an impression of flowing jellyfish.

I don't know if tenses were used correctly. I mean second part mainly because I want there conditional, not future tense. I mean done facture! I see my efforts laying on my chair!

Comment: The tenses look fine to me, but I have no idea what your sentence means.  What have you created?

Comment: Maybe a "fractal" (sort of mathematical art) was intended instead of "fracture" ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have used the tenses correctly. Here *would* expresses an unreal condition, because you have not actually created this facture yet.

Added to address comment:
The present perfect is a present tense, not a past tense.

Anyway, you can still use *would* here even though "it is already done." In this case, you are explaining what you have been trying to do, even when you have already accomplished it.

> I have been aiming at creating a facture which would give an impression of flowing jelyfish (and here you can see that I have done so).

Comment: No it is already done . I used present perfect because I can see my effets laying on my chair.

Comment: So present perfect can stay? and it wouldn't mean that I havent done it yet?